# Open local network adresses without internet connectivity on iOS

Tags: ios, network, safari

I've building an appliance that offers a control panel on an integrated WiFi hotspot.

People using iPads however experience the situation where there are connected to the WiFi network, but cannot access the local appliances pages address with Safari, as Safari is telling them that the page can't be opened, as there is no interent connection.

I've got some device to test with, and in fact this happens on an 6th generation iPad with recent software updates.

Is there any way to work around this bug, maybe by Safari / iOS settings?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such bug. It is entirely possible to access local network addresses without internet connectivity on iOS.

You either have a misconfiguration on your hotspot (i.e. incorrect DHCP settings - this is quite common) or your user's enter the wrong thing in Safari.

Comment: I've tested myself  - IP and DHCP is fine. iPad acquires an address, shows captive portal (which is indeed loaded from the LAN address), but Safari refuses to work - only shows the no internet connection message in every tab used to access the very same address as the portal already managed to show.

Comment: Also same configuration works for PC, Mac desktop browser, Android mobile etc.

Comment: I’m not sure that you have tested it correctly - I have seen many do this wrong. Including large companies with experienced programmers. Include the DHCP information in the question and we can check it. Often you’ll see that you have it misconfigured to include a router, which you should not do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue in the past few days with iOS 16 and 17 beta.

If the DHCP server doesn't give a gateway IP (even your LAN isn't connected to the internet) it will not work with DNS hostname (even if the DNS server is reachable) but will work with IP.

It looks like Safari/iOS is refusing to do anything if there's no gateway defined in the setup as long as you need to use a domain name to access your lan resources.

What I did was add a gw to my DHCP server configuration (even if my router doesn't have access to internet) and it immediately started working great.

I know your message is old, but still hope this will help you or someone else.